# Problem with ecommerce_purchase for Android Release + Firebase + Google Tag Manager + Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have problem with  ecommerce_purchase event on Android. All another events are working properly + it's working fine for debug version. I see events in Firebase console and Google Analytics.

Problem occurs only on release version of Android app. I see purchase events in Firebase console but not it Google Analytics (connected via Google Tag Manager and Firebase).

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

`ecommerce_purchase` event does not trigger automatically.

you can refer below link for more detail.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

anyway, I just trigger `ecommerce_purchase` event manually, and It's work well.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE

Please note that: `price` and `currency` must be transfer at the same time

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putDouble(Param.PRICE, 1.0);
params.putString(Param.CURRENCY, "USD"); // e.g. $1.00 USD
```

Comment: It didn't work even after i trigger this event.but i can see the event in debugging.Any idea ??

Comment: some events trigger by firebase default .